# Magento 2: how to send POST request to REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I am struggling with POST REST API's in Magento 2 as I am quite new to it.
If possible, can anyone provide me one example for POST like creation of product or add to cart using oAuth and admin account, please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Look at [how to get admin token](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html), and check out [available web API endpoints documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html) (pay attention to `catalogProductRepositoryV1`).

Answer (score 1):

Sample to create bundle product :

```
{"product":{
 "sku": "Bundle2",
 "name": "Bundle Product 2",
 "attribute_set_id": 4,
 "price": 12,
 "status": 1,
 "visibility": 4,
"weight": 3,
 "extension_attributes": {
  "bundle_product_options": [
      {
          "title": "Select",
       "required": true,
       "type": "select",
       "position": 0,
       "sku": "Bundle2",
       "product_links": [
         {
          "sku": "eraser",
          "is_default": false
        }
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 "custom_attributes": [
   {
     "attribute_code": "multiple_select",
     "value": ["4"]

     }
     ]
    }
  }
```